# Fetch data from manytomany relationship along with onetomany

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, one-to-many, prefetch

If we consider the three following models: clients, companies, contacts.
Clients can purchase goods from several companies and a company has many clients. Moreover, a company has several "contact" types (email, fax, phone,...).

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    fname= models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)
    company= models.ManyToManyField(to='Companies', related_name='provider', blank=True)

class Companies(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=45, null=False)

class Contacts(models.Model):
    contact= models.CharField(max_length=45)
    type= models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE)
    company= models.ForeignKey(to='Companies', related_name= 'company_contacts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For a given client, I would like to retrieve all the companies he purchased from along with all the company's details (stored in the model "Contacts"). In SQL, with an intermediate table (clients_companies), I will do:

```
SELECT cl.fname, cp.name, ct.contact, ct.type 
  FROM Clients cl 
  JOIN Clients_Companies cc ON cl.id = cc.clients_id
  JOIN Companies cp ON cp.id = cc.companies_id
  JOIN Contacts ct  ON cp.id = ct.companies_id;
```

Which will give:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+
| fname   | name      | contact         | type   |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+
| Client1 | Company A | 333-555-1234    | phone  |
| Client1 | Company A | email@email.com | email  |
| Client1 | Company B | 202-555-0191    | phone  |
| Client1 | Company B | 202-555-9999    | fax    |
| Client1 | Company B | arg@arg.com     | email  | 
+---------+-----------+-----------------+--------+
```

In django, I'd like something similar to:

```
data = [
     {'Company A':[{'type':'phone', 'contact':'333-555-1234'},
                  {'type':'email', 'contact':'email@email.com'}],
      'Company B':[{'type':'phone', 'contact':'202-555-0191'},
                   {'type':'fax', 'contact':'202-555-9999'},
                   {'type':'email', 'contact':'arg@arg.com'},],
     }]
```

Any suggestion to solve this is welcome. Also, if you have sources to learn querying data using django ORM I will be really happy as I found really difficult to work the django way when coming from SQL.

Comment: One tip, if you're coming with SQL, is to [look at the SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) generated by your Django queries. That will help you hone your understanding of how the ORM works.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's what I'm doing but unfortunately I can't get the query I want.